# How to merge cells in Excel?

Tags: c#, excel

I have a list of objects and I am trying to dedicate *three* rows for every object and I am using the "Office Open Xml library" with this routine:

```
int row = 1, col = 1; 
for (int i = 0; i < MyList.Count * 3; i+=3)
{
    MySheet.Cells[row + i, col, row + i + 1, col].Merge = true; // merge two and get a "result"
    MySheet.Cells[row + i + 1, col, row + i + 2, col].Merge = true; // merge "result" with third row
}
```

However it pops an error saying *can't merge already merged cell*.

So the question is **How to merge *more than two cells* in Excel**?

Comment: You already wrote that code - just change the indexes. If you want to merge three rows, use `row + i + 2` instead of `row + i + 1`

Comment: No it doesn't. The indexes specify a *region*, not a single cell. Everything in Excel is based on ranges. Even a cell is treated as a single-cell Range

Comment: @pan I did not know it was a range and I feel dumb :))))) thanks I see it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indexes specify a range of cells, not only two adjacent cells. To merge cells across three rows you can write

```
MySheet.Cells[row + i, col, row + i + 2, col].Merge = true;
```

Or you can merge a 3x2 block

```
MySheet.Cells[row + i, col, row + i + 2, col+1].Merge = true;
```

Everything in Excel is a range. Even a single cell is treated as a single-cell. This makes working with single cells a bit weird but it makes applying styles and formulas a lot easier

Comment: Worked like a charm. One Q though, if I want to write inside that range/block of merged cells. What value should I use as an index? Any value between [`row + i` and `row + i + 2`] would work fine?

Comment: Most of the methods you use on cells are actually inherited from Range. Save the range to a local variable and set the range's `Value`, eg `var myRange=MySheet.Cells[row + i, col, row + i + 2, col]; myRange.Merge=true; myRange.Value = 5;`

Comment: Cool, I think I will use your way but just to mention that I tested it and _**Any**_ single cell index within a range of a block/range of merged cells will work completely fine as an index to the _**whole**_ block/range of merged cells

Answer (score 0):

Use this for merge 2x3

```
MySheet.get_Range(MySheet.Cells[row, col], MySheet.Cells[row + 2, col + 3]).MergeCells = true;
```